# Setting a Silverlight Image.Source throws runtime error

Tags: c#, silverlight, image

When I set the .Source of an Silverlight Image control I get a runtime error.
This is the code:

```
<Image
        Height="240"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="12,348,0,0"
        Name="Image_Artikel"
        Stretch="Fill"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="300" />
```

Here is the codebehind, I checked if a.Afbeelding had a value.

```
        Artikel a = this.Grid_Artikelen.SelectedItem as Artikel;
        Uri u = new Uri(a.Afbeelding ,UriKind.Absolute);
        BitmapImage i = new BitmapImage(u);
        this.Image_Artikel.Source = i;
```

I get the following error in my browser (IE)

Line: 54
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4009
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: Element is already the child of another element.

What am I doing wrong? I am actually quite annoyed as why It takes 3 lines of code to simply display an image in Silverlight, and then it doesn't even work. LOL

Comment: You wouldn't get that error from the code you've shown us.  You are doing something else that is attempting to add an element to the display that is already in the visual tree.  A static resource that ought to be a DataTemplate for example.

Comment: I added the code that I actually want to use. Even though I still get the error with my previous code.

Comment: Anthony is right, this code should not be able to cause such an exception...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
<Image
        Height="240"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="12,348,0,0"
        Name="Image_Artikel"
    Source="http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo29.png"
        Stretch="Fill"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="300" />
```

Your codebehind is working fine in my test. Can you give some more information, e.g. where do you call you codebehind?

Comment: I cannot use your code because I set a different image each time I select a different item in my datagrid. When the datagrid_SelectionChanged occurs I set a new Image.Source.

Comment: Have you tried binding the source to the SelectedItem of the DataGrid. Something like this Source="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.ImageProperty"}. Or better, bind the SelectedItem Of the DataGrid to your DataContext and reference the SelectedItem in your DataContext to the source property.
<DataGrid ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelItem, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
<Image Source="{Binding SelItem, Path=ImagePath}".../>

Comment: Do you have a tutorial how to do this? I usually do all binding in codebehind but I see a lot of alternatives on the XAML side. I would like to know more.

Comment: You should have a look at the MVVM Pattern (I strongly recommend to use it). Here is a link http://jesseliberty.com/2010/05/08/mvvm-its-not-kool-aid-3/, but if you google it, you find a lot of links. Here is the msdn article regarding data binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this in the java script or remove the whole js exception handling

```
 function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            ...
            var errorType = args.ErrorType;
            var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

            if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
              return;
            }
...
```

Silverlight has sometimes problems when loading images, for example, when they are not at the source you specified.

Comment: How can I do this? The Silverlight app runs when I press F5 and I don't have a Website hosted Silverlight project

Comment: You can specify a page in the project properties, under Debug: "Specific Page". But it's probably easier to create a separate webproject (I recommned this, because you this way you have all  files (html/aspx, javascript, clientaccesspolicy etc) you need to host it on a webserver later) and i like it better for debug...